# How can I set the quality to You Tube video using jquery?

Tags: youtube

I want to give users to set the quality parameter for the you tube video they are embedding in their pages. But, I could not find any perfect information on this. I had added options as 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p and 1080p. But how can I set them?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this plugin? [Tikuu.com](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_4)

With it you can use the property "preferredQuality", setting it to your preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720.

Hope that helps,